# Where does one acquire lost parts from toolboxes or toolsets?

Tags: tools, drill

I purchased a Durabuilt toolbox many years ago, but some of the tools from the box have gone missing (ie. a vice grip and a screwdriver).

[image]

I'm trying to buy those missing parts. So that when I take the toolbox with me, I don't have to bring extra an extra vice grip and another screwdriver. I'm wondering if there's a place to purchase missing tool parts individually. Or do I need to go to a big-box hardware store and try each one that's on sale to see which one fits the toolbox?

The same goes for the drill head from my [Black and Decker drill](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00T2VJ93C) [image: Black and Decker drill]. This drill head was easily worn out. I'm trying to get another drill head with a more durable material but still fits the bit storage slot

[image]

I've gone to Walmart to look for a drill head, but they only sell a set of 3 [Hyper-tough drill heads](https://www.walmart.com/ip/Hyper-Tough-3-Pack-2-inch-Phillips-Screwdriver-Bits-AU85040K-Phillips-sizes-Ph1-Ph2-and-Ph3/219415626), not individually. I've heard that Home Depot used to sell a single drill head individually but has since stopped selling them. Where does one acquire lost parts from toolboxes or toolsets?

Comment: shopping questions are off topic here

Answer (score 1):

Depends.  If they're a quality set like Craftsman, the manufacturer has each of the constituent tools in their catalog, and you can just buy another one. The designs are stable and don't change much. In the old day you'd go into a store, but these days you'd buy new on the manufacturer's website, Amazon or used on eBay.

Unfortunately big-box stores are infested with "Chinese specials", which they cut costs many ways, including having absolutely no supply chain, ISO 9001, service or support.  If a vendor orders 100,000 kits then they buy up 100,000 quantity of each of the tools in the kit, make a blow-molded case that matches those tools, and when the 100,000th kit is stacked in the container, they throw the molds away. In those cases, forget it. If you paid less than $100 for that kit, most likely it's one of those.

As far as shopping for tools, if you want to limit yourself to what's in big-box that's fine, but you can also look at better hardware stores, the Snap-On truck for tools of incomparable quality, and mail order from tool specialty websites, or Grainger/McMaster, or if you're careful, Amazon or eBay. I do well buying Craftsman on eBay.

You might want to learn more about your tools; drills are actually for drilling holes using fluted *drill bits*.

You actually own a drill-driver, and that is a screwdriver *bit* for a drill-driver. Any respectable hardware store or lumberyard will have a little drawer full of them, and they'll sell you one for under a buck, or 25 cents for the short ones. They also sell many small parts including all manner of bolt and screw very inexpensively; you get a bag and write the item quantity and price with a grease pencil on the bag.  So 4 x bolt @ 11 cents each, 4 x washer @ 6 cents each, etc.

I know you think you "save big money" at the big-box stores, but that's illusionary. Big-box has its own high cost of doing business; mall rents aren't cheap and neither is automation. Those bolts are 3 for $1.29 in a bag with a barcode. The cost is in the bag and barcode, and they make it 3 so it seems like less of a ripoff. That's why Walmart wouldn't sell you 1 bit.

Bits are commodities/consumables. They wear out all the time especially the Philips, because people use power drivers on Philips head screws, and they go  BRAPAPAPAPAPAPAPAP and think that's normal - they're really camming out the screw head (never get that off) and wrecking the bit.  This is why I use TORX head screws (Robertson also works OK), I have yet to wear out a TORX.  To avoid BRAPAPAP, I use a "speed wrench" with a "bit holder" as it gives speed with very fine control. Also lets me leave *an actual drill* in the drill for any pre-drilling.

Comment: Thank you Harper for going into so much deals. Do you think this could be a good replacement? https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B06XYRCX4S/ref=ox_sc_act_title_2?tag=slickdeals09-20&ascsubtag=15a297c6c50411ecb7dff6873aadd9b10INT&smid=ATVPDKIKX0DER&psc=1

Comment: @spacenet those are #2 Robertson bits, those will work if those are the screws you want to drive.